# undefined method `scaler=' for #<Class:0x00000003aa6a10> (NoMethodError) Workless Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, autoscaling

I am using the below gems for auto scaling of worker on heroku.

`````
````
   gem "workless", "1.1.1"
   gem "delayed_job",         "2.0.7"
   gem "rails", "~>2.3"
````
In production.rb, I have added the below code
````
   config.after_initialize do
    p Delayed::Job
    Delayed::Job.scaler = :heroku
   end
````
But after starting the rails server I am getting the below error. .

````
   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job(id: integer, priority: integer, attempts: integer, handler: text, last_error: text, run_at: datetime, locked_at: datetime, failed_at: datetime, locked_by: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
`method_missing': undefined method `scaler=' for #<Class:0x00000003aa6a10> (NoMethodError)

````
`````

Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you ever had this working before on Heroku?  Back in 2013 you needed to, 'add one worker,' agree to the service's terms, then relaunch your app.  You couldn't (can't?) use a 'worker' until you've agreed to these terms - even if you aren't paying for one.  You can read more here: https://github.com/lostboy/workless/issues/42 .  This could be completely wrong because you are actually getting the undefined method on the `Job` object (rather than jobs simply not starting) - but I'm hoping it's an easy-to-diagnose-fix of Heroku workers causing you the issue.  Keep us updated.

Comment: Nope ... Its failing in my local system due to scaler method call on Delayed::Job.

Comment: When it fails on your local system, are you launching your server while using the development environment - or are you using the production environment?  Does this fail on Heroku?